# А у вас, какая длина строки? (Стиль кода)

Tags: code-style

Собственно стало интересно есть ли какие то стандарты/рекомендации к кол-ву символов в строке?

По дефолту в IDE Intelij установлено 100 символов.
На сегодняшний день вряд ли кто то кодит на экране разрешения меньше чем HD (1280x720).
Соответственно и длина строки должна увеличится.

Кто что думает по этому поводу?

Comment: Зависит от ЯП, в php пишу комманду в строку, не зависимо от длинны, в Delphi пишу не больше стандартных 100 символов, но стараюсь не доходить до этого предела, если параметы функции превышают длинну в 100 символов - 1 параметр на 1 строку.(100 симв просто число с потолка, не знаю сколько в IDE по умолчанию)

Comment: Вот есть [Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html), рекомендующий 80 символов потому что это ширина терминала. Есть от этого толк или нет - неизвестно.

Comment: Зависит от языка: где-то 80, где-то 120. Но не более 120, потому что часто нужно смотреть диффы, а это две версии кода рядом: даже на широком мониторе станет некомфортно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov для дифов можно использовать 2 одинаковых монитора стоящих вплотную к друг другу(собственно у меня всегда стоят 2 монитора, на втором или справка открыта или иная "вспомогательная" информация, т.е. то что не требует постоянного внимания, но куда иногда полезно поглядывать)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков - а у ваших коллег нет двух мониторов (в данный конкретный момент), и вообще вы в отпуске и срочно понадобилось что-то подправить с помощью маленького ноута... (Но я не отрицаю, что широкий монитор это здорово, а два-три еще лучше. И работать в отпуске - зло).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я комментировал лишь ту часть где "нужно делать дифы, а это неудобно даже на широком экране"(простите за вольную цитату), ничего более, сам стараюсь не делать длинных строк ибо это не удобно прежде всего при оптимизации кода, и вообще затрудняет беглое чтение. но почему то на php в частности не прижилось у меня это(может потому что никто эти коды не читает и они чисто для себя)

Comment: В мой 1366x768 влезает всего 100 символов, пишу строки 79 символов

Comment: в 1366px влезает всего 100 символов? это у вас шрифт огромный или отступ большой. Я использую шрифт Monospaced размер 14, максимальная длина символа 10 px получается 1000px на 100 символов (Если писать все в верхнем регистре)

Comment: Чем меньше, тем лучше. Мы же читаем код как последовательность действий. Обычно одно действие записывают в одной строке. Чем меньше у вас символов в строке, тем быстрее вы сможете читать. Конечно, делать все идентификаторы одно-двух-трех символьными это перебор, тут важен здравый смысл и опыт. Учтите, что в самом деле  длинные идентификаторы никто толком полностью не читает и в следствии этого иногда возникают долго не отлавливыемые ошибки